# How to set application path in appium server?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, appium

```
File app = new File ( appDir );
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability ( MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "" );
capabilities.setCapability ( MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "1262dec2" );
capabilities.setCapability ( MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID );
capabilities.setCapability( MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.1.1" );
capabilities.setCapability( MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "appium" );
capabilities.setCapability( MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.4.16.1" );
capabilities.setCapability( MobileCapabilityType.APP, app );
driver = new AndroidDriver( new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723//wd//hub" ), capabilities);
```

When I have run the above code in eclipse, it displayed the following error

> info: [debug] Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource

I have tried all the capabilities for a long time. Can anyone help to solve the problem?

Comment: What error do you get at the client side? Seems that this is just informative message, not a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

You should have .apk file with you and provide path in file path for mac(/filename.apk) on windows(\filename.apk)
example:

```
String apkpath="/Users/fidel/Downloads/Test.apk";
File app=new File(apkpath);
```

then set the below capability

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

Connect device and pair your system
Run Appium (you can see log on Appium)